# How to assert a trigger event text in cypress which is generated in console tab

Tags: javascript, cypress

I have a very specific usecase but I am not getting how to proceed.
I have a button which generates a trigger event in console tab under network tools on clicking.
I know we use cy.stub() but i don't know the whole procedure
The usecase is

1. Open website
2. Click on a button
3. Verify an event is triggered (consent callback executing) in console tab of network tools
4. I again click on a button
5. Verify that event is not triggered again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `cy.intercept` to listen for network calls. Combining this with aliasing, you can assert that a certain call has only been triggered X amount of times at the end of your test.

```js
cy.intercept('/foo') // create intercept
  .as('foo'); // alias the intercept
cy.get('button')
  .click() // trigger the network call
  .wait('@foo'); // waits for the intercept to run
cy.get('button')
  .click() // hopefully does not trigger the network call
cy.get('@foo.all') // get all calls intercepted with the alias 'foo'
  .should('have.length, 1); // assert that the list of calls has a length of 1, meaning it was only intercepted once (and not twice)
```

Comment: will this work for events triggered in console tab also
also i want to intercept the event with certain text consent callback executing

Comment: `cy.intercept` will intercept network requests. Browser events (such as the callback executing) are not able to be intercepted by `cy.intercept`.

Comment: That being said, I'm not positive that intercepting the browser event has much difference than intercepting _the consequence_ of the browser event (in this case, the network request). If clicking a button triggers some callback which triggers a network request, checking that the network request is/isn't happening _essentially_ is also checking that the callback happens.

Comment: It worked but with slight modification